# Matrix question any short cut?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $$A =\begin{pmatrix}k & 2 \\ 2 & k \end{pmatrix}$$
be a $2 \times 2$ matrix then what is the determinant of $A^3$?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Find $\det A$ and express $\det A^3$ using $\det A$.

Answer (score 0):

as a rule:

$detA^3= (detA)^3$

answer: $(k^2-4)^3$

I encourage you try doing it on your own and to read about determinant rules.